# pyserial RS232 to Ethernet converter? will work?

Tags: python, ethernet, rs232

If I use an RS232 to Ethernet converter like [this](http://www.usconverters.com/index.php?main_page=page&id=70&chapter=0) and connect it to the lan network by transmitting data from a printer or any other serial device, is it possible that I can read the serial information from another PC on the lan network using [pyserial](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) only? trying to communicate using IP: port or I need drivers on the client PC to create a virtual port that converts TCP / IP to RS232, regardless of whether I work with linux, windows or mac
I hope you understand me, Thank you.

[Maybe the solution is here?](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/url_handlers.html)

Comment: The driver installed on the host PC creates a virtual serial/COM port.  You would access the remote RS-232 port just as if it were actually a local port.  The installed driver is part of the OS, and should hide from application programs all details of the actual Ethernet transfer.

Comment: search google "Python read serial (RS-232) data over TCP/IP". I don't understand why he connect successfully to ethernet converter using socket connection and this way can read the original serial message :/

Comment: You are doing a poor job of (a) expressing what the actual issue is, and (b) comprehending the explanations available on the web and what I've written.  You seem intent on ignoring the straightforward solution, and prefer to do the complex alternative.  BTW if there is a web page that is relevant, then post the link to it.  I'm not going to search for it.

Comment: (a) I do not want to depend on drivers to create virtual ports, but through ip: port connection (b) I understand the web and your answer but it is not a solution for me. I think the solution is from pyserial without drivers "serial_for_url()" (c) BTW thx

Comment: You are probably underestimating the functionality of the driver.  Besides the actual transfer of data, the driver also performs device configuration and status monitoring.  If the device manufacturer does not document this interface, then you could have a lot of reverse engineering to perform in order to get this to actually work reliably.

Comment: Hi. I tested finally the setup. It is working fine transmitting serial rs232 data through LAN/WLAN.
I can recover the message using pyserial without use virtual com from the RS232 to Ethernet server conversor. Only need this: serial_for_url("socket://<host>:<port>/?logging=debug")

Answer (score 1):

I tested finally the setup. It is working fine transmitting serial rs232 data through LAN/WLAN.

I can recover the message using pyserial without use virtual com from the RS232 to Ethernet server conversor. Only need this `serial_for_url("socket://<host>:<port>/?logging=debug")`